# Highcharts: Percentage stacking bar chart with overlayed line graph (secondary axis)

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to create a dual axis highchart. On one axis I would like a percentage stacked bar chart, and on the other axis I'd like a line chart. Although I'm close (I have a 'normal' stacked bar chart overlayed by the line chart), I can't seem to get the bar chart to stack as a percentage, even after specifying stacking as 'percentage'.

Here's what I have:

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column',
            width: 550,
            height: 400
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Title'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: [1, 2, 3]
        },
        yAxis: [{
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'Percentage'
                }
            }, {
                min: 0,
                opposite: true,
                title: {
                    text: 'Total Count',
                style: {
                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[4]
                }
            },
            labels: {
                style: {
                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[4]
                }
            },
        }],
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b> ({point.percentage:.0f}%)<br/>',
            shared: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                pointPadding: 0.2,
                borderWidth: 0,
                stacking: 'percentage'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'A',
            type: 'column',
            yAxis: 0,
            data: [5, 1, 2]

        }, {
            name: 'B',
            type: 'column',
            yAxis: 0, 
            data: [1, 1, 2]

        }, {
            name: 'C',
            type: 'column',
            yAxis: 0, 
            data: [2, 3, 1]

        }, {
            name: 'D',
            type: 'column',
            yAxis: 0, 
            data: [4, 3, 3]

        }, {
            name: 'Total Count',
            type: 'line',
            yAxis: 1, // Secondary axis (a total of all in the primary axis)
            data: [12, 8, 8]

        }]
    });
});
```

JSFiddle: [jsfiddle.net/natecarrier/5mX7s/](http://jsfiddle.net/natecarrier/5mX7s/)

Comment: it's `stacking: 'percent'` not `stacking: 'percentage'`. http://jsfiddle.net/natecarrier/5mX7s/1

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to replace percetage with percent.
2. [alignTicks](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.alignTicks) set as false, will disable `aligning ticks`.

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/5mX7s/5/

Comment: Can't believe I missed that. Thanks for the help!